# En AWK como hacer output de 18 lineas

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Tengo que hacer un output de 18 lineas:

```
ls -lh ~cis140u/lab6examples |awk  '{print" \t",$8, $6,-$7,"\t",$NF , $5, "\t",$10; } '
```

en orden de FECHA ARCHIVO TAMAÑO

está bien?

Comment: ¿Ya probaste su funcionamiento, tuviste algún error o la salida no fue la esperada?

Comment: No fue lo esperado, no en el orden que necesito hacer el output :(

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y agrega: a) una muestra del archivo que estás procesando, apenas suficiente para hacer pruebas. b) la salida que obtienes y c) el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 3):

Mira la salida por defecto de `ls -lh`:

```
$ ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 m m 0 Aug  6 11:42  archivo
-rw-r--r-- 1 m m 0 Jul  6  2012 'archivo viejo'
```

Si ignoras la primera línea, puedes ver cuáles van a ser los campos que va a leer `awk`:

```
|          1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |   6 | 7 |     8 |       9 |     10 |
+------------|---|---|---|---|-----|---|-------|---------|--------+
| -rw-r--r-- | 1 | m | m | 0 | Aug | 6 | 11:42 | archivo |        |
| -rw-r--r-- | 1 | m | m | 0 | Jul | 6 |  2012 |'archivo | viejo' |
```

La **fecha** corresponde a los campos 6, 7 y 8, pero como ves el campo 8 no es consistente.

El **archivo** correspode al campo 9 y como tenemos un nombre de archivo con espacios, también al campo 10.

El **tamaño** es el campo 5.

Así que si no tienes nombres de archivos con espacios o archivos cuya última fecha de modificación sea "antigua", es bastante sencillo (saltamos el primer registro con el condicionale `NR>1`):

```
 $ ls -lh | awk 'NR>1 { print $6,$7,$8"\t"$9"\t"$5 }'
 Aug 6 11:42     archivo 0
 Jul 6 2012      archivo 0
```

Esto es, el campo $6, $7 y $8 seguidos de una tabulación, seguidos del campo $9, seguido de una tabulación, seguido del campo $5.

Sin embargo, como ves, en este ejempplo no es tan sencillo, pues nos cortó el nombre del archivo con espacios y la fecha no es consistente.

Para obtener un resultado consistente en la fecha puedes usar el argumento `--full-time` de `ls`:

```
$ ls -lh --full-time | awk 'NR>1 { print $6"\t"$9"\t"$5 }'
2017-08-06      archivo 0
2012-07-06      archivo 0
```

Sin embargo, aún tenemos problemas con el nombre del archivo, por lo que debemos hacer algo más complicado si queremos seguir con `awk`:

```
$ ls -lh --full-time | awk 'NR>1 { archivo=$9;for (i=10;i<=NF;++i) archivo=archivo" "$i; print $6"\t"archivo"\t"$5 }'
2017-08-06      archivo 0
2012-07-06      archivo viejo   0
```

Quizás una forma más sencilla de hacerlos puede ser `stat`:

```
stat -c "%y %n %s" *
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Esto es muy frágil.

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por el vínculo. Precisamente la fragilidad de este enfoque era lo que quería demostrar, con casos que pueden ser frecuentes y sin entrar en casos más extremos.